# Variable or field declared void C++

Tags: c++

I am making a school assignment, but I am getting a strange error. I have tried to google it, but nothing helped.

So I have a file called main.cpp. Within this file I have some includes and code.

This:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "RentalAdministration.h"
#include "Limousine.h"
#include "Sedan.h"


void addTestDataToAdministration(RentalAdministration* administration)
{
    string licencePlates[] = {"SD-001", "SD-002", "SD-003", "SD-004", "LM-001", "LM-002"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Car* sedan = new Sedan("BMW", "535d", 2012 + i, licencePlates[i], false);
        administration->Add(sedan);
    }
    for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Car* limousine = new Limousine("Rolls Roys", "Phantom Extended Wheelbase", 2015, licencePlates[i], true);
        administration->Add(limousine);
    }
}

int main( void )
{  
    RentalAdministration administration;
    addTestDataToAdministration(&administration);
}
```

So the compiler tells me that the variable: "RentalAdministration administration" does not exist.

So if we have look in my rentaladministration header. We see this:

```
#ifndef RENTALADMINISTRATION_H
#define RENTALADMINISTRATION_H

#include <vector>
#include "car.h"


class RentalAdministration
{
private:
std::vector<Car*> Cars;
Car* FindCar(std::string licencePlate);
Car* FindCarWithException(std::string licencePlate);

public:
std::vector<Car*> GetCars() const {return Cars;}

bool Add(Car* car);
bool RentCar(std::string licencePlate);
double ReturnCar(std::string licencePlate, int kilometers);
void CleanCar(std::string licencePlate);



RentalAdministration();
~RentalAdministration();
};
#endif
```

This is the exact error:

```
src/main.cpp:18:34: error: variable or field ‘addTestDataToAdministration’ declared void
 void addTestDataToAdministration(RentalAdministration* administration)
                                  ^
src/main.cpp:18:34: error: ‘RentalAdministration’ was not declared in this scope
src/main.cpp:18:56: error: ‘administration’ was not declared in this scope
 void addTestDataToAdministration(RentalAdministration* administration)
```

Help will be appreciated!

### Edit:

I am getting warnings in sublime for the Sedan and Limousine headers. Something that has to do with some static constants. I think it was called a GNU extension. Maybe it has something to do with it.

Even when I comment the call of that function out. I get the same error.
I am calling that function nowhere else.
Some people say that the cause might be in these headers:

```
#ifndef LIMOUSINE_H
#define LIMOUSINE_H

#include "Car.h"
//c


class Limousine : public Car
{
private:
    bool needsCleaning;
    bool hasMiniBar;
    static const double priceperkm = 2.5;

public:
    double Return(int kilometers);
    void Clean();

    bool GetHasMiniBar() const { return hasMiniBar;}
    void SetHasMiniBar(bool value) {hasMiniBar = value;}

    Limousine(std::string manufacturer, std::string model, int buildYear, std::string licencePlate, bool hasminiBar);

    ~Limousine();

};
#endif
```

2:

```
#ifndef SEDAN_H
#define SEDAN_H

#include "Car.h"
//c



class Sedan : public Car
{

private: 
    int lastCleanedAtKm;
    bool hasTowBar;
    bool needsCleaning;
    static const double priceperKm = 0.29;
public:
    void Clean();

    int GetLastCleanedAtKm() const {return lastCleanedAtKm;}
    void SetLastCleanedAtKm(bool value){ lastCleanedAtKm = value;}

    bool GetHasTowBar() const {return hasTowBar;}
    void SetHasTowBar(bool value) {hasTowBar = value;}

    bool GetNeedsCleaning() const {return needsCleaning;}
    void SetNeedsCleaning(bool value){needsCleaning = value;}


    Sedan(std::string manufacturer, std::string model, int buildYear, std::string licencePlate, bool hastowBar);
    ~Sedan();

};
#endif
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: You should fix your includes, `RentalAdministration.h` uses `string` but does not include corresponding header, `using namespace std;` is written infront of other headers (you should get rid of it completely), you should put library headers *after* your own headers.

Comment: Most likely the compiler is still processing code at that point as though inside some function or class scope or something like that, due to a missing `}` or similar in a previously included header.

Comment: Remove the included files "car.h", "Limousine.h", and "Sedan.h" and see if error persists

Comment: @Amadeus Still got the same errors.

Comment: @aschepler  Couldn't find missing }. I will look again

Comment: @VTT That's something that my teacher did, I will change it. Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't need to be a encylopedia of edits. Please make it into a single, cohesive, coherent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the terminal has somehow solved this error. I got another error this time, which I solved already. I missed the destructor. It stood in the header file, but not in the cpp file.

Buggy terminals...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> class Limousine : public Car
> {
> private:
>     static const double priceperkm = 2.5;
>     ...
> }
> ```

Remove the `static` and declare the member simply as `const double`, example:

```
class Limousine : public Car
{
private:
    const double priceperkm = 2.5;
    ...
}
```

The error message `‘RentalAdministration’ was not declared in this scope` indicates that the right header file for `RentalAdministration` was not included. Check the file names to make sure class declaration for `RentalAdministration` is in the right file.

Comment: I checked it with two other people. The declaration is correct. But thank you for the static correction.